# Unable to instantiate activity after a checkout that made some random changes

Tags: android, eclipse, git

```
01-28 15:35:46.105: D/AndroidRuntime(7819): Shutting down VM
01-28 15:35:46.105: W/dalvikvm(7819): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b85700)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{in.altersense.radioremote/in.altersense.radioremote.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "in.altersense.radioremote.SplashScreenActivity" on path: /data/app/in.altersense.radioremote-2.apk
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "in.altersense.radioremote.SplashScreenActivity" on path: /data/app/in.altersense.radioremote-2.apk
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
01-28 15:35:46.110: E/AndroidRuntime(7819):     ... 11 more
```

The code has no errors. But after the forced checkout the android build paths and properties where  all changed and I had to clean the project and reset the Java Build Path to reach a stable version but then the above error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the changes happened during a checkout and the project properties were altered I removed the Project from eclipse and deleted the files from the disk. I did a

```
git reset --hard
```

and imported the files to eclipse as a new android project with existing sources and everything worked fine.